# How to get comment_ID by post_ID in wordpress

Tags: php, comments

I used `get_comment()` but its parameter is `$comment_ID` which I has to enter manually for previous comments from `wp_comments` instead of that I need to get current comment means last updated comment author name based on the `post_ID`. However `wp_posts` and `wp_comments` are related with `post_ID` and `comment_post_ID`, so I can use SQL query to get comment_ID I tried 
`$wpdb->get_results('select comment_ID from wp_comments where comment_post_ID = 1')` 
its even manual process but at-least I want to pass comment_ID by fetching from database but could't do that query results nothing so is there any way to get current comment_ID for a post_ID I can get post_id by `$post->ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_comments( $args )` to get all the comments for a post.

```
$args= array(
    'author_email' => '',
    'ID' => '',
    'karma' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'offset' => '',
    'orderby' => '',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'parent' => '',
    'post_id' => 0,
    'post_author' => '',
    'post_name' => '',
    'post_parent' => '',
    'post_status' => '',
    'post_type' => '',
    'status' => '',
    'type' => '',
    'user_id' => '',
    'search' => '',
    'count' => false,
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'meta_query' => '');
```

You can set `post_id` here and get all comments related to that post. It is same as your query.

```
$comments = get_comments(array('post_id'=> 'your post id'));
$comment_ids = array();
foreach($comments as $comment):
    $comment_ids[] = $comment->comment_ID;
endforeach;
print_r($comment_ids); // edite print_r(comment_ids);
```

For reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

Comment: I need to get comment author name when ever a new comment is generated for a particular post, although may be I could get the same from `get_comments()` function if I could access last comment, means highest `comment_ID` for particular `post_id` _THANKS_

Comment: You can use `orderby` value as `comment_date_gmt` for get latest comment at top. After getting its `0` element you get latest comment. Then `comment->comment_author` will give you author name for latest comment :)